# Android/Java: Find an image match (Big image contains small image)

Tags: java, android, image, search, find

Thank you for reading my question.

I want to check the big image contains another small image.
I'm trying Image Search. There are 2000+ more small images and I want to compare these with one big image.

If big image contains small image, it is obvious that the big image contains almost of small image.

There is no small image's rotation. The ratio of image is same.

But the size is different. I mean if the small image size is 100x100 pixel, the another small image (in the big image) size could be 150x150, 50x50.. and else.

I know there is OpenCV's template matching.
But it makes my app heavy and takes a long time.
I think I need another way.

Would you recommend something I need to do?
I really appreciate it if you could give me just a little hint.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of these mentioned in the below link some are paid some are free
https://blog.cloudoki.com/mobile-image-detection/